# Migration from SQLServer to MySQL-Server DB with HTML code

Tags: mysql, sql-server

For days I am trying to export from my SQL-server table and to import into MySQL-table.

I can't solve the problem with HTML-Mails in one field of the table, which contains everything the HTML-code can have, such as \r\n linebreaks, quotation marks, maybe even | pipe-sign.

I tried exporting a concatenated string from SQL such as 'Insert Into MYSQL_table (field1, field2, ...)

I tried CSV-Files with terminal.command

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'G:/Test2.csv' 
INTO TABLE insectum.tblolnachrichten
CHARACTER SET utf8mb4
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|@@|' 
ENCLOSED BY ''
ESCAPED BY '\n'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

tried workbench, php with CSV-files, I think everything.

But everywhere I fail due to another occurence of any sign in the HTML-Code in this field.
There are about 5000 lines to be transfered intyo Mysql-table, more than 100 MB in CSV-File.

I even tried field separator like |@@| .

The content of this one field is wrapped with like this:

```
|@@|myHTML-field|@@|
```

Did not work as well.

Any idea what I could do to tell Mysql at import to keep content of a field for import and do not make a break anwhere?

Answer (score 0):

Well, as no one had an answer for me, I did it the boring but obviously easierst way:
I linked SQL and MySQL into empty MS Access database and copied from one to another by taking about 300 rows every copy.

It worked and as I just have to do ONE time, it is OK.